# Bizzare std::string behavior when using pthreads

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, g++, pthreads

I'm having a strange std::string problem. It has to do with passing a string within a structure through a thread. Essentially I build a string by concatenating a vector of strings and use this built string as the string within a structure. I then pass the structure as an argument to a thread, access the string member variable, and try to print it. A mindboggling behavior occurs:

If I print the string first before the thread's creation, then the string prints while the thread runs. However, if I do not print the string before the thread's creation, then the string does not print while the thread runs and has size 0. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


struct data
{
    std::string msg;
    int id;
};

std::string GetString(std::vector<std::string> &args);
void *F(void *vargp);

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    std::vector<std::string> args;
    args.push_back(std::string("skip"));
    args.push_back(std::string("one"));
    args.push_back(std::string("two"));
    args.push_back(std::string("three"));
    args.push_back(std::string("four"));
    args.push_back(std::string("five"));

    data d;
    d.id = 123;
    d.msg = GetString(args);

    /* Removing the below commented line escapes the error. 
     * With the line commented the string has size 0 in F.
     * However when it is compiled and run, the string in F 
     * has its actual size and the correct output appear.
     * WHAT IS GOING ON?
     */
    // cout << "before: " << d.msg << endl;

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, F, &d);

    pthread_exit(0);
}

void *F(void *vargp)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    data d = *(data *)vargp;
    cout << d.msg << " " << d.id << endl;
}

std::string GetString(std::vector<std::string> &args)
{
    std::string str(args[1]);
    for (int i=2; i!=args.size(); i++)
        str += " " + args[i];
    return str;
}
```

I compiled the function via

```
g++ test.cpp -pthread -o test
```

where test.cpp is the name of the above source file.

Comment: What does pthread.h contain? Why do you prefer it to the standard [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)?

Comment: @Hector See [this `<pthread.h>` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html). It's the standard "native" thread library on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of *undefined behavior* as the variable `d` goes out of scope and is destructed when you to `pthread_exit` in the `main` function. The pointer in your thread function is no longer valid once the original variable goes out of scope.

For an intermediate solution, allocate `d` dynamically instead. For a long-term solution consider using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead.

Comment: Ok you're right. Replacing pthread_exit(0); with while(1); does the intended behavior. But I would like the program to terminate as soon as the thread terminates and using while(1); requires a CTRL+C to abort. Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Comment: @Sanfer: allocate `d` on the heap with `new` and then pass the pointer to your thread. Now your thread owns the pointer and is responsible for calling `delete`.

Comment: @Sanfer Like I said, allocate dynamically instead, the memory you allocate with e.g. `new` will not go out of scope.